# Changing visibility of a window by button on a different window in wpf?

Tags: wpf, forms, visibility

I have set the visibility of my forms to false, and now i want a button on a different form to show the hidden forms without having to create new forms in a WPF how would i do this?

Comment: By 'form' you mean WPF Window?

Comment: yes Lupu Silviu i do mean that. thanks for clearifying for others

Comment: Well, you will have use `System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows` . This contains all the Windows of your application. You can then try to hind your hidden window and make if visible (use either Title, or another wa to find it)